# Error, while try to navigate to another screen using StackNavigator in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `StackNavigator`, I have added button in the toolbar, and when clicking that button, I want to navigate to another screen, instead of that, when I press button, I get an error:

> "Can't find variable navigate"

. How to fix that?

```
  static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Review Jobs',
      headerRight: <Button tittle="Settings" onPress={()=> navigate('settings') } />
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use methods from navigation while setting [`navigationOptions`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#RouteConfigs) you can use an arrow function rather than just setting it as a plain object

**Example**

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  title: 'Review Jobs',
  headerRight: <Button tittle="Settings" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('settings') } />
});
```

Comment: When I'm using your code, I get such error: "navigation.navigate is not a function. In "navigation.navigate('settings")  navigation.navigate is undefined ".

Answer (score 3):

The right syntax would be

`static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: 'Review Jobs',
  headerRight: <Button tittle="Settings" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('settings') } />
});`